# pjsip 2.8 TRANSPORT_ADAPTER_SAMPLE segmentation fault

Tags: pjsip

I am testing pjsua from pjsip 2.8 on Centos 7.5 with `#TRANSPORT_ADAPTER_SAMPLE` uncommented and when it receive RTP packages it gets segmentation fault, see results from gdb.

Program received signal `SIGSEGV`, Segmentation fault.

```
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffea227700 (LWP 27034)]
0x00007ffff7077898 in on_rx_rtp () from /lib64/libpjmedia.so.2
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7077898 in on_rx_rtp () from /lib64/libpjmedia.so.2
#1  0x00007ffff7082ef1 in srtp_rtp_cb () from /lib64/libpjmedia.so.2
#2  0x00007ffff70836a9 in on_rx_rtp () from /lib64/libpjmedia.so.2
#3  0x00007ffff5f984dd in ioqueue_dispatch_read_event () from /lib64/libpj.so.2
#4  0x00007ffff5f9986f in pj_ioqueue_poll () from /lib64/libpj.so.2
#5  0x00007ffff7065a00 in worker_proc () from /lib64/libpjmedia.so.2
#6  0x00007ffff5f9a926 in thread_main () from /lib64/libpj.so.2
#7  0x00007ffff4f8add5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#8  0x00007ffff49b6b3d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

(gdb)

Thanks

Comment: Disable the value of TRANSPORT_ADAPTER_SAMPLE in pjsua_app.c or just check with breakpoints in the method.